# gcd and divisibility in ℤ

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying the divisibility properties in ℤ, there's a passage in my manual I find difficult to grasp. I don't understand why it is consequent that $d_1$ divides $d_2$ in the following statement:

> Let $d_1 = \gcd(b, c)$ and $d_2 = \gcd(ab, c)$. Now $d_1 = \gcd(b, c)$
>   ⇒[($d_1$ divides $b$) and ($d_1$ divides $c$)]. Consequently, $d_1$
>   divides $ab$, and so it follows that $d_1$ divides $d_2$.

Couldn't be $d_1$ greater than $d_2$, so that it cannot divide $d_2$?

Comment: No, because all divisors common to $ab$ and $c$ are divisors of $d_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d_2$ is GCD of $(ab,c)$ which means it is the greatest among all the numbers that divide both ab and c. Since $d_1$ is one such number dividing both ab and c, hence, $d_1\leq d_2$.

Comment: You even may add that $d_1$ is a divisor of $d_2$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\gcd(a,b)$ is an integer number such that

- $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $a$ and $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $b$
- if an integer $c$ divides both $a$ and $b$ then $c$ divides $\gcd(a,b)$

Now by assumption you have that $d_1$ divides $b$. This means that there exists an integer $x$ such that $b=d_1x$. Therefore, $ab=d_1ax$. Hence $d_1$ divides both $ab$ and $c$. By the second property of $\gcd(ab, c)$, you have that if a number divides both $ab$ and $c$ then it must divide $\gcd(ab, c)$. Hence $d_1$ divides $\gcd(ab, c)$.